# automake gives segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: automake, 24.04

Whenever I invoke `automake`, it gives a segmentation fault (code dumped) error. Due to this, I am unable to compile and install anything from the source!

For example:

```
$> automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.16.5
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>
       and Alexandre Duret-Lutz <adl@gnu.org>.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Note the error at the end!**

My system details are:

```
$> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch)
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble

$> uname -a
Linux vinay-desktop 6.8.0-11-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb 14 00:29:05 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Initially, I thought this was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/automake-1.16/+bug/2059079), but it looks like this is a problem only with my system!

Any pointers? Am I missing any package or any failed dependency?

Comment: AFAIK `automake` is a perl script - does `/usr/bin/perl --version` work, or does that also segfault?